# Parsing error: Expression expected. eslint

Tags: typescript, eslint

```
interface Address {
  street: string,
}

export const getAddress = (address: Address | null) : string =>
  address?.street ? `${address?.street}`
    : '0000 Default Dr';
```

Does anybody know am I getting `Parsing error: Expression expected. eslint` on `address` in `address?.street ?` ?

Eslint rules both for the `.js` and `.ts`:

```
 {
      "extends": [
        "plugin:cypress/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
      ],
      "overrides":
        {
          "files": ["**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
          "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
          "parserOptions": {
            "project": "./tsconfig.json"
          },
          "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier", "react-hooks", "jsx-a11y"],
          "extends": [
            "eslint:recommended",
            "react-app",
            "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
            "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
            "prettier"
          ],
          "rules": {
            "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": "off",
            "no-empty-function": 0,
            "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
            "no-use-before-define": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error"]
          },
          "settings": {
            "import/parsers": {
              "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
            },
            "import/resolver": {
              "typescript": {}
            },
            "react": {
              "version": "detect"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the ES version is set to the default value. Optional chaining (`address?.street`) is ES2019. By default, ESLint expects ECMAScript 5 syntax. If you want to enable ES2019 syntax add this to `parserOptions`: `ecmaVersion: '9'` (or `'2019'`) to your eslintrc ([link to docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options)).

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple things that can cause this error -> [link to article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-expression-expected-error)

In your case declaring const and variable export in different lines would work.

Apart from what is mentioned in the linked article, and specific to my case,
I got this error when I was chaining statements without using brackets and added an in-line comment at the last.

This was the original statement I wrote that throws the error:

```
if (selectedHour < startHour - 1) for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) elapsedMinutes.push(i); // disable all minutes
```

The solution was to remove the comment from the end and place it on a separate line:

```
// disable all minutes
if (selectedHour < startHour - 1) for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) elapsedMinutes.push(i);
```

Hope this helps! Happy Coding!